# Memcached in a trusted shared environment?

Tags: apache, memcached

We are a university IT organization that hosts all of the university's websites on several shared servers on our server room floor. We have several VMs, each running its own instance of Apache as a web server for each respective server.

If we were going to setup a memcached server, is it feasible to use it as a shared instance?

If shared by several servers, or even multiple web apps running on the same server, what's the best way to keep each app's cache stores separate? Prefix the key?

Would each VM require its own instance of memcached, or could we setup 1 memcached server and allow our multiple VMs to read/write to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wrote [bucket engine](https://github.com/membase/bucket_engine) specifically to allow for a large number of memcached virtual instances running under a single process.